# Aligned equations in a colored box

Tags: color, align, boxes, framed, empheq

I would like to put a set of aligned equations into a colored box. After a quick search on tex.stackexchange, I have found the following solution to put (apparently) *one* equation in a color box :

```
>\newcommand{\boxedeq}[2]{\begin{empheq}[box={\fboxsep=6pt\fbox}]{align}\label{#1}#2\end{empheq}}
>\newcommand{\coloredeq}[2]{\begin{empheq}[box=\colorbox{lightgreen}]{align}\label{#1}#2\end{empheq}}
```

thanks to the `empheq` and `framed` packages. When I tried to use the `align` environment with `coloredeq` it did not work :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\boxedeq}[2]{\begin{empheq}[box={\fboxsep=6pt\fbox}]{align}\label{#1}#2\end{empheq}}
\newcommand{\coloredeq}[2]{\begin{empheq}[box=\colorbox{red}]{align}\label{#1}#2\end{empheq}}

\coloredeq{eq:myequation}{
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = {} g(x) \\
     & = h(x) 
\end{align*}
}

\end{document}
```

I shall also mention (in case this information is useful) that I would like to include this colored set of equations into a Beamer presentation. How can I use the `coloredeq` command with the `align` environment ?

Comment: You are missing a `\begin{document}`. Have you really found those definitions here? With the label included? You are using an `align*` which does not use labels at all. Please clarify a bit, what you want to get. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't solve the error in your code, but it answers the question you mentioned in the title. You can use [Tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en) package that as its title suggests, creates color boxes. It is very well [documented](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) and it has many features. You can also use it in your Beamer presentation easily.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\definecolor{yourcolor}{RGB}{128, 0, 0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align,colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=yourcolor]
f(x) & = {} g(x) \\
     & = h(x) 
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and if you want unnumbered align environment, simply use `ams align*` in the options of the environment. In fact, there is a library (`\tcbuselibrary{theorems}`) which allows you `ams` like environment within tcolorboxes.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer !! Quick question : how can I change the box color to a given color, defined by its RGB triplet ? I cannot find this information in the manual of the `tcolorbox` package.

Comment: @jibounet `colframe=yourcolor`

Comment: @jibounet, exactly as LaRiFaRi mentioned. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Note unless one really wants an equation number each line this should be a `\begin{split}...\end{split}` inside an `ams equation`.  Also the brackets `{}` in the first line of the equation are spurious.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing different environments here. In your MWE, you are putting an `align*` inside of an `align` which is defined in your preamble. Moreover, you are giving a label but what should that label refer to? To which line, to which number (especially if you do not want numbers)?

I changed the definitions to your needs. I hope I guessed right.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand{\boxedeq}[1]{\begin{empheq}[box={\fboxsep=6pt\fbox}]{align*}#1\end{empheq}}
\newcommand{\coloredeq}[1]{\begin{empheq}[box=\colorbox{red}]{align*}#1\end{empheq}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\boxedeq{%
    f(x) &= g(x) \\
    &= h(x) 
}
\coloredeq{%
    f(x) &= g(x) \\
    &= h(x) 
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is  a solution that defines  a `colouredeqs` environment, which has the same syntax as  the `empheq` environment (optional key-valued arguments, and AmS environment as a mandatory argument). The background colour can be changed in the preamble via `\colourlet{bkgcolour}{…}`. It relies on `xcolor` and `empheq`.

Comment aside, it is pointless to load `amsmath` if you load `empheq`, since the latter loads `mathtools, which loads`amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{empheq}

\colorlet{bkgcolour}{Thistle2!40!}
\newcommand*\mycolouredbox[1]{%
\colorbox{bkgcolour}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}
\newenvironment{colouredeqs}[2][]{%
\setkeys{EmphEqEnv}{#2}%
\setkeys{EmphEqOpt}{box=\mycolouredbox,#1}%
\EmphEqMainEnv}%
{\endEmphEqMainEnv}

\begin{document}

\begin{colouredeqs}[left = \color{VioletRed4}\empheqlbrace]{align*}
  f(x) & = g(x) \\
  & = h(x)
\end{colouredeqs}

\end{document}
```

[image]